# How to remove permanently those error prompts while using openbox gnome?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, xorg, openbox

How to remove permanently those error prompts while using openbox gnome? Such as: update ubuntu latest release, this kind of errors etc, how to permanently disable them so that it does not show in front of my presentation.

[image]

**Follow up:**

a) How do i kill that screen shot error box?

```
$ cat /etc/default/whoopsie

[General]
report_crashes=false

$ apport-cli

*** Send problem report to the developers?

After the problem report has been sent, please fill out the form in the
automatically opened web browser.

What would you like to do? Your options are:
  S: Send report (69.7 KB)
  V: View report
  K: Keep report file for sending later or copying to somewhere else
  I: Cancel and ignore future crashes of this program version
  C: Cancel
Please choose (S/V/K/I/C): I
```

b) How do i kill that update notification dialog box?

```
$/etc/xdg/autostart# vim update-notifier.desktop 
#NoDisplay=true
NoDisplay=false
:wq

$ cat update-notifier.desktop | grep NoDisplay
NoDisplay=false
```

No more disturbing popup's now.

Final follow up:

```
root@sun-Inspiron-One-2320:~# apt-get -f remove apport update-manager update-manager-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apport-gtk : Depends: apport (>= 0.41) but it is not going to be installed
 opera:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3.2) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3.6-6~) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libfontconfig1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.16.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 (>= 0.10.16) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 (>= 0.10.15) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libice6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libsm6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.6.27) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxrender1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxt6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: fonts-liberation:i386 but it is not installable or
                       ttf-liberation:i386 but it is not installable or
                       ttf-mscorefonts-installer:i386 but it is not installable
              Recommends: flashplugin-nonfree:i386
              Recommends: cups-client:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 update-notifier : Depends: update-manager-gnome but it is not installable or
                            update-manager but it is not going to be installed
 xdiagnose : Depends: apport but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the first dialog, try uninstalling `apport`. For the second, you can remove `update-manager`and `update-manager-core`, assuming that @mikewhatever's got the correct package names (I'm not on an Ubuntu machine at present).

You can do it this way:

```
sudo apt-get remove apport update-manager update-manager-core
```

I'm fairly confident about apport, because that's the program that handles automatic bug reports. Instead of mucking about with the configuration, just get rid of it since you don't like it.

Comment: Thank you. It works now perfectly. Was confusing which packages was poping out.

Answer (score 1):

The error above is probably related to whoopsie, the crash report daemon. You could disable it by editing `/etc/default/whoopsie`, and changing `report_crashes=true` to false. As for for updates, the best solution, IMHO, would be to install them, however, if that's not possible, disable the update checker and the update notifier.

What other errors do you get?

Comment: i did you way. But still same after 10 time reboot having "report_crashes=false"

Comment: See my follow up, option 2 works to kill the screenshot. But i have another issue the updates prompt always daily it shows up. How do i kill that one?

Comment: Hm..., not sure. What you did about the update-notifier would only unhide it from autostart programs. To disable it, that entry must be removed from /etc/xdg, but since you probably don't need an update manager, uninstall `update-manager` and `update-manager-core`, or whatever you have installed there. I don't think those are OpenBox packages.